# How To Get The Number Of Days Between Two Dates In Emeditor

Tags: emeditor

In Emeditor, how do i get the number of days between 2 date columns? Example:

- Column A: 25/11/2022
- Column B: 29/11/2022

-> Column C: 4 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
1/1/2022,1/2/2022,
1/1/2022,2/2/2022,
1/1/2022,3/2/2023,
```

The 3rd column must be an *empty* column. Assuming the date format is the system date format. In this case, it is the US format (m/d/yyyy).

1. Select the 3rd empty column by clicking the 3rd column heading.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the **Replace** dialog box, and enter

- **Find**: `.*`
- **Replace with**: `\J d1=new Date(cell(-2)); d2=new Date(cell(-1)); diffTime=Math.abs(d2-d1); Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000*60*60*24));`
- Set the **Regular Expressions** and **In the Selection Only** options.

3. Make sure the selection (3rd column) is *empty*, and click **Replace All**.

The result will be:

```
1/1/2022,1/2/2022,1
1/1/2022,2/2/2022,32
1/1/2022,3/2/2023,425
```

**References**

- [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)
- [EmEditor Help - Replacement Expression Syntax](http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html)

Comment: Thank you! I works only using the American date format. How will the formula work for dd/MM/yyy date format?

Comment: It should work fine with dd/MM/yyyy as long as the system date format is also dd/MM/yyyy. Did you check Windows locale settings?

Answer (score 0):

In a single line, you may execute it in this way:

`parseInt(txt.split(',').map(x => x = new Date(x)).map((a,b,ar) => Math.abs(a-ar[i+1])).shift()/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 10)`

Code:

```
const txt = '1/1/2022,12/31/2022';
console.log(parseInt(txt.split(',').map(x => x = new Date(x)).map((a,b,ar) => Math.abs(a-ar[i+1])).shift()/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 10));
```

Output:

```
364
```